# Angular 2 patchValue in Form Array

Tags: angular

i have a form with a form array:

```
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
        id: [this.model.id],
        customer_id: [this.model.customer_id],
        orderlines: this._fb.array([])
    });
```

The form array:

```
    return this._fb.group({
        id: [orderline.id],
        order_id: [orderline.order_id],
        factor: [orderline.factor],
    })
```

Now i want to change the value of the factor field within in the method setFactor(i). The i is the index of the form array orderlines.

```
setFactor(i) {
    this.myForm['orderlines'[i]].patchValue({ factor: 99 }) <--- no error but no change in form
    this.myForm.patchValue({ orderlines[i].factor: 99 }) <-- error

}
```

How can i use patchValue to change a value in a form array?

EDIT

this will give me the value i want to change:

```
console.log(this.myForm['controls']['orderlines']['controls'][i]['controls']['factor'].value);
```

Comment: Neither of those attempts makes sense. `'orderlines'[i]` is indexing into the string `'orderlines'`, so you'd end up with e.g. `this.myForm['o']`. In the second version, presumably the error is that you haven't defined `orderlines` anywhere (as far as you've shown) prior to indexing into it. Also that control array is empty, so it's not clear what indexing into it would achieve. Could you give a [mcve]?

Answer (score 4):

the following worked:

```
this.myForm['controls']['orderlines']['controls'][i]['controls']['factor'].patchValue(99)
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. Is there any other more cleaner way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

First create a method that returns the form array

```
  GetOrderLinesArray() {
    return this.myForm.get('orderLines') as FormArray;
  }
```

Then to patch the value:

```
setFactor(index) {
this.GetOrderLinesArray().controls[index].get('factor').patchValue(99);
}
```